# Validate tags for an attr_accessor in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a project model inside my app where I have:

```
attr_accessor :tags
```

`tags` is a field coming from the form submitted that gets into the controller for further setup. I want to make sure when the form is submitted the size of this array/tags is not more than 5. how can i do that? I am using rails 4.

This is how the form looks like:

```
<%=f.autocomplete_field :tags, autocomplete_tags_project_path,'data-delimiter' => ',', :multiple => true%>
```

**autocomplete_field comes from a gem I am using.**

I am unable to use something like this:

```
validates :tags, :length => {:maximum => 5}
```

Any help is appreciated.

---

UPDATE: The form that gets to the controller looks something like

`"tags"=>["test,
 tets,
 tst,
 test,
 test,
 test,
 tets,
te st,
 tes"],`

Comment: Any reason why you are unable to use that validation?

Comment: @Pavan, I can add more than 5 tags and the validation doesnt take effect

Comment: @psharma - you are not overriding `tags=`, `tags` or `assign_attributes` method, are you?

Comment: @BroiSatse umm, i dont think so. not that i am aware of.

Comment: @psharma - try adding custom validation `validate :test_me`, define `test_me` method to `raise tags.inspect` and please paste the error. Also it might be handy if you show how you are handling tags data (`... into the controller for further setup`)

Comment: @BroiSatse ok,  i have update the question as to how the form submits and the kind of data. I have also update the method in the model to ```validate :test_tags
  def test_tags
    raise tags.inspect
  end```. Now the error raised is ```RuntimeError```. and points to the line ```raise tags.inspect```

Comment: and if i do something like ```   if self.tags.size > 5 raise "error" end```. I get an error saying ```undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass```.

Comment: Your tags returns an array with a single coma-separated string value. Most likely you need to override the `tags` setter to split this string into separate tags. How is your field defined in your form? (view)

Comment: @BroiSatse umm i think i already have that in the question, if i understand your question right.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try

```
validate :tag_size

def tag_size
  errors.add(:tags, 'YOUR ERROR MESSAGE') if tags.size > 5
end
```

Comment: I tried it and get `undefined method 'size' for nil:NilClass`